# Can a Business Coordinator become a project manager

Tags: career, roles

I am working as a Business Coordinator in an IT company. I have completed Bachelors of Technology in Information Technology.

Is there a chance for me to become a Project Manager?

If yes, then what is the way?

Answer (score 2):

As the matter of fact anyone could become a project manager.

1. Read some books and materials related to it.
2. Pass some certification which is valuable in your region/company.
3. After you are ready inform your company that you want to become one.
4. Introduce some things that could be improved on project management in your company.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Alexander's answer:

Read some books and materials related to it.

- The Mythical Man Month
- Peopleware

Pass some certification which is valuable in your region/company.

- PMP
- PMI-ACP

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal path to become a pm.

In a nutshell it might look like this:

1. Start learning hard and soft skills
2. Work in the field
3. Get a degree
4. Get a job
5. Get a certification
6. Never stop developing and growing

Anyway, in a real life everything can be in an absolutely different order.

You might find a step-by-step process of becoming a project manager in [this](https://casual.pm/how-to/become-project-manager) detailed guide.

Answer (score 0):

PM was and is a job role as much as it is--if not, even more so--a titled job.  At some stage in your career, someone is going to ask you to lead something to deliver something of necessity in a finite period of time.  Recognize this as a project and document it in your experience.  And when you perform it, use PM formal rigor to manage it even if it is over kill for that project because you want to practice it, understand how it works, and make mistakes so you can learn from it.

So, until that time comes, read and read PM books, any of them; they're all valuable.  Focus on PM controls, like risk and quality management, cost and schedule control, change control.

As you deliver these small asks and you deliver them well, eventually you'll get the label.